# Pythonic Variable Assignment

Tags: python, coding-style

At the moment I have a large section of code that looks like this:

```
daily_stats.Turnover = int(row[2])
daily_stats.Cars = int(row[0])
daily_stats.Cash = int(row[29])
daily_stats.Card = int(row[33])
daily_stats.Other = int(row[31]) + int(row[35]) + int(row[37])
daily_stats.Exit = int(row[43])
daily_stats.Manual = int(row[42])
daily_stats.Open = int(row[47])
```

This continues for about 30 lines and, while it gets the job done, isn't very tidy or pythonic.

Is there a cleaner way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could save your data in a dictionary and then iterate over it while using `setattr` to set the attributes in `daily_stats`.

In your dict the values could take either integers or lists (depending on whether they're a single value from `row` or multiple summed values). As such you can use a `try:... except:...` block to set a sensible value using `setattr`.

Below is a simplified version using random values. Note that it assumes that `daily_stats` supports setting normal arbitrary attributes.

```
class DailyStats(object):
    pass

row = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']

daily_stats = DailyStats()

items = {'Turnover':0,
         'Cars':1,
         'Cash':[2,3,4]}

for item, value in items.items():
    try:
        val = sum(int(row[val]) for val in value)
    except TypeError:
        val = int(row[value])
    setattr(daily_stats, item, val)

print(daily_stats.Turnover) # 10
print(daily_stats.Cars) # 20
print(daily_stats.Cash) # 120
```

Comment: Not sure if it affects it, but I don't have control over the row[] variable, it comes from a CSV export of data from another service.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as long as you can get its rows via `row[whatever]` then it should work fine. Mine is just a list because I had to create an example to work with.